# Oracle DB what is the difference between ALL, USER and DBA Objects?

Tags: oracle

As the title suggests, I am trying to understand the structure of our Oracle DBs a little more and a little confused by the ALL, DBA & USER Objects.

A quick SQL

```
select count(*) ALL_OBJS from all_objects where owner = 'XXXX';
select count(*) DBA_OBJS from dba_objects where owner = 'XXXX';
select count(*) USER_OBJS from USER_OBJECTS; (logged on as XXXX)
```

Returns:

```
  ALL_OBJS
----------
      1591

  DBA_OBJS
----------
      1632

 USER_OBJS
----------
      1632
```

As I presume our user has DBA rights and the USER objects and DBA objects are the same? But what are ALL objects? 
If you are looking to clear out a User's SCHEMA which would you remove from or would you drop objects from all three?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the ALL\_OBJECTS and DBA\_OBJECTS different when you have DBA Role?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88865/are-the-all-objects-and-dba-objects-different-when-you-have-dba-role)

Comment: @topshot the suggested duplicate, despite being the accepted answer, doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: If you try to identify objects that don't appear among `DBA_OBJECTS` it might give you a hint about the reasons: `select owner, object_name, object_type from dba_objects minus select owner, object_name, object_type from all_objects`

Answer (score 1):

- `USER_OBJECTS` are your objects, i.e. the objects where the current user is the owner
- `ALL_OBJECTS` are all objects which you can access. These are of course your own objects from above plus objects from other schemas where access is granted to you.
- `DBA_OBJECTS` are all objects in the database. As a DBA you have access to all objects, thus `ALL_OBJECTS` and `DBA_OBJECTS` should be the same if you are connected as DBA.

If you want to remove **all** objects from a user then the best command would be `DROP USER xyz CASCADE;`

**Do not** delete anything from `XXX_OBJECTS` view. Use `DROP ...` commands to removed those objects.